# Oracle PL SQL command-line utility

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

Is there any kind of program on oracle which helps you with typing?
For example there is SQL Prompt on MS SQL Server, and I want to know if there is something like this on PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle ecosystem is slightly different in approach from MS SQL Server. Traditionally Oracle has offered a top-notch RDBMS but its supporting tools have been rather basic, with third-party vendors filling in the gap. This contrasts with the MS approach which offers tightly integrated environments for managing and developing against MSSQL.

So yes, PL/SQL Developer (the Allround Automations product) has code completion for PL/SQL and SQL elements. Quest TOAD has it too. Oracle came late to the IDE game but its Oracle SQL Developer product does code completion. Finally, the new [Oracle SQL Command Line tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html) offers statement completion, which is another reason it is superior to the venerable SQL*Plus tool.

These are all separate tools, even the Oracle ones, until Oracle 12cR2 which does bundle SQLcl in the download.